# use custom font android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, fonts

In assets I create a folder "Fonts", and inside there are fonts which I want to use. Besides that, after I registered the font in properties I set "Copy to outer directory: copy always"
After that,

```
 <style name="Editor" >
<item name="android:textColor" >#575656</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint" >#78788a</item>
<item name="android:background" >#efefef</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily" >Assets.Fonts.acadnusx</item>
```

I wrote this code, but the objects that use this style do not have changed font.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your linked code doesn't show , but I assume you have that at the end in your actual project correct?

Does using something like:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
```

As an entry change the colors for you?

Past that I would need to see the rest of your code to see why it isn't working.  Hope this helps you some!

Answer (score 0):

`var tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Main_tvTitle);
// Font is in the Assets folder ("Assets\fonts\PermanentMarker.ttf")
tv.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/PermanentMarker.ttf");`

[Use custom fonts in Xamarin.Android](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79411/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-xamarin-android)